# Use IP address, port and domain name in url in ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to add IP address,port and domain name as a parameter in url in ajax request:

```
url = "AuthServlet?Host="+host+"&port="+port+"&Domain="+domain;
xmlhttp.open("POST", url, false);
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

Where host is IP address.

For example:

- host   = 10.0.0.1
- port   = 7070
- domain = xyz.com.

When I do like this servlet is not called. How can I call servlet and process request?

Comment: Why using POST when you pass all parameters in URL?

Comment: @Dev-null-dweller: Thanks for pointing it out. I'll make it GET but the issue still remains that is how to pass ip,port and domain name in request?

Comment: Did you check the url in your browser? May be try the absolute address of the url like: `http://yourwebserver/AuthServlet?...` May be it's a typo or a wrong path to the resource.

Comment: @Mic: when I try in browser address bar it works fine.

Comment: You pass a relative url, which will be different depending on from which page you are posting it from. Try add a prepending slash, "/AuthServlet?..." it your servlet action is directly in your web root.

Comment: @jishi: adding `/` didn't help.

Comment: You really need to log what errors you are receiving with either firebug or fiddler in order for people to be able help you.

Comment: @jishi: I have downloaded firebug. Now how can I see the error. What I try is put a breakpoint in function then try to debug it but when I come to xmlhttp.open(... line the debug does not work any more it just go. Nothing in the watch/stack tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make the request to some distinct address, you have to actually form the URL. That's the whole point of the URL in fact. And you have to choose between your host address and your domain name - you can't have both.

However, even if you do that, be warned that if the resulting URL is for a domain different from the one from which your page was served, then it won't work anyway because of browser security rules.

If, on the other hand, your "AuthServlet" is simply expecting parameters, then there's nothing wrong with what you're doing except that the parameter values should be encoded:

```
var url = "AuthServlet?Host=" + encodeURIComponent(host) + 
  "&port=" + encodeURIComponent(port) +
  "&Domain=" + encodeURIComponent(domain);
```

(*edit* — fixed bogus references to non-existent "escapeURIComponent" routine :-)

Comment: No I don't want to send request to some distinct address. I want to pass IP address, port and domain name as a parameter in request to servlet.

Comment: @Harry Joy then you're already doing that properly.  How do you know that the servlet is not called?

Comment: @Pointy: Put alerts at the before and after `xmlhttp.open("POST", url, false);` and also put debug points in servlet. The first alert is called. No debug point is reached.

Comment: @Pointy: `escapeURIComponent` is not working. Host is not empty but `escapeURIComponent(host)` is not running at all.

Comment: Have you tried debugging with Firebug? That should show XML HTTP traffic. You could also try the [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) Firefox plugin, which traces all HTTP activity.

Comment: @pointy: its working now but did not solve the problem. Still the same issue.

Comment: Well, as I said, that looks like a fine URL.  What happens when you just type the URL (complete with your parameters) into the browser address bar?

Comment: @pointy: I try to debug using firebug but when come at xmlhttp.open(.. line the debug goes into an infinite processing. No new event happens.